# Как записать результат промиса в переменую

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Имеем следующий код

```
let result = async () => {
   return await fs.readFile('header.html', 'utf8');
};
```

при вызове данной функции ожидалось увидеть в консоле содержимое файла "header.html":

```
console.log(result()); // увы было выведено Promise { <pending> }
```

Не приговор подумал я, зная что раз функция возвращет промис, нужно применить к нему метод `then`.

После доработки функции таким образом:

```
let result = async () => {
   await fs.readFile('header.html', 'utf8')
   .then(res => { return res }); };
```

снова запустил консоль и к своему удивление обнаружил что:

```
console.log(result()); // увы снова было выведено Promise { <pending> }
```

На всякий случай попробовал организовать вывод непосредственно в функции вот так:

```
let result = async () => {
   await fs.readFile('header.html', 'utf8')
   .then(res => console.log(res)); };
```

и наконец после вызова функции `result();` увидел заветное содержимое файла в консоли.

Однако мне не нужно содержимое файла в консоли. Мне нужно записать его в переменную, а этого у меня как я не пытался так и не вышло.

Даже при вызове функции я добавлял метод `then` к функции:

```
console.log(result().then(res => { return res }));
```

и даже так:

```
console.log(result().then(res => { return res }).then(res => { return res })); );
```

Также объявлял функцию порождающую промис как Function Declaration:

```js
    function prom() {  
    return fs.readFile('header.html', 'utf8')  
      .then(function (data) {  
         return data;  
      });  
    }
```

и затем уже используюя промежуточную функцию:

```js
    async function func() {  
      let res = await prom();  
      return res;  
    }
```

делал вызов в консоль:

```js
    console.log(func());
```

Но снова и снова получал злополучное `Promise { <pending> }`.

Как же всё таки записать данные в переменную ведь делаю всё согласно теории, или может быть я чего-то не допонимаю?

Comment: Почему мой вопрос был дважды отклонён? Видимо человек который грешит подобным, плохо разбирается в теме, раз отклоняет грамотно составленые вопросы. Очень жаль что нет формы обратной связи, в которой можно было бы дать соответствующую оценку столь не компетентному подходу